# Как получить SHA1-Digest?

Tags: zip, sha1, signature

Мне нужно получить SHA1-Digest с файла для подписи zip в manifest.mf командой терминала. Я знаю, что подпись необязательна, но всё же.

Comment: В Linux можете воспользоваться утилитой `sha1sum`

Comment: Мне нужно не просто sha1, а sha1-digest.

Comment: Краткий взгляд на образцы в сети подсказывает, что SHA1-digest очень похож на `base64` (такая утилита тоже есть) от SHA1-hash

Comment: это вы jar подписываете?

Comment: Я подписываю zip (updater-script) для установки через recovery в Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использую OpenSSL

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha1 <YOUR-FILE> | base64
```

**Edit**

На самом деле еще много способов, зависит от платформы и ЯП

Например, в Nodejs

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";

crypto.createHash('sha1')
    .update(fs.readFileSync('path-to-file))
    .digest('base64')
```